# Use regex in powershell to get name of server from string with repeatable format

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use powershell to get the server name from a string in which the format is the same every time.  I create a text file using a command in HP's Data Protector.  Examples of strings are...

```
   host="ts-sve-serverT.ca.mycompany.com"  
   host="ts-sve-serverG.ca.mycompany.com"  
   host="ts-sve-serverA.ca.mycompany.com"
```

There are 3 spaces at the beginning.  I'm interested in extracting the server name after the first set of quotes and before the first period.  The server name may contain 0 to 2 dashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the `-match` operator, as [latkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088962/1630171) suggested, or the `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
$names = gc 'C:\path\to\your.log' | Select-String '"(.*?)\.' | % {
  $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
}
```

The above requires PowerShell v3. On earlier versions you'll have to expand the matches like this:

```
$names = gc 'C:\path\to\your.log' | Select-String '"(.*?)\.' `
  | select -Expand Matches `
  | select -Expand Groups `
  | select -Last 1 Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$serverNames = gc 'c:\logfile.txt' |?{ $_ -match '"([^\.]*)\.' } |%{ $matches[1] }
```